# What's a better time complexity, $O(\log^2(n))$, or $O(n)$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity, polylogarithm

(By $O(\log^2(n))$, I mean $O((\log n)^2)$ rather than $O(\log(\log(n)) )$

I know $O(\log(n))$ is better than $O(\log^2(n))$ which itself is better than $O(\log^3(n))$ etc. But how do these compare to $O(n)$? Is there a certain point where when you keep tacking on these logs, they surpass linear time complexity? When does this happen?

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\log x\right)^n}{x}=0$ for any natural number $n$ (think of a proof!) - so no matter how many (finitely many) $\log$s you stack, $\mathcal{O}\left((\log x)^n\right)$ is better than $\mathcal{O}(x)$.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. I think you accidentally gave a variable two names; we can't compare a function of $x$ to a function of $n$. Sticking with $x$, @ultralegend5385's point, in which $n$ has a different meaning, is this: for $x>1$,$$0<\log x^{1/(2n)}<x^{1/(2n)}\implies\frac{\log^nx}{x}<\frac{(2n)^n}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithmic_function

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\log{n} \lt n$ [[ I will leave out $O(\cdot)$ to keep it readable & easy to type ]]

We want to know whether there is some $P$ where $\log^{P}{n} \lt n \lt \log^{P+1}{n}$ that makes the Polylogarithm larger than linear.

Take $log(\cdot)$ here :
$\log{\log^{P}{n}} \lt \log{n} \lt \log{\log^{P+1}{n}}$
$P\log{\log{n}} \lt \log{n} \lt (P+1)\log{\log{n}}$
$P\log{\log{n}}/\log{n} \lt 1 \lt (P+1)\log{\log{n}}/\log{n}$

We know that $\log{\log{n}}/\log{n} \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ , hence this is :
$P \times 0 \lt 1 \lt (P+1) \times 0$
$0 \lt 1 \lt 0$
Contradiction !
Hence there is no such $P$ to make Polylogarithm linear.